# "There was too much truth in this to ignore" meaning in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "I don't hate her," said Hermione loftily. "I just think she's an absolutely appalling teacher and a real old fraud. But Harry's already missed History of Magic and I don't think he ought to miss anything else today!"
>
> **There was too much truth in this to ignore**, so half an hour later Harry took his seat in the hot, overperfumed atmosphere of the Divination classroom, feeling angry at everybody.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

I'm not sure what the meaning of "There was too much truth in this to ignore" is in this context. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, as one often finds in fiction, rather more words than necessary to get the point across.

Essentially, it is saying that the idea that he oughtn't to miss anything else that day was true, and therefore he went to Divination.

The subtler side of it is suggesting that it might not have been entirely correct, there might be some argument to be had, but that it was true *enough* that it wasn't worth arguing.